# Writing content to file at exact position using shell script

Tags: shell, file

I want to write a file with contents similar as shown below.( You can copy this content to PSPAD to check the position )

00C00000000000120170531
06                       0006488863669006111060110090302073350000000                     201705310000000002599
9900000000002599000001

File contains below details which I will be getting as a result of database query execution and will be storing it in variable-

Unique ID-0006488863669006111 - Starts from 26th position - length 19

Sequence - 0000000002599 - Starts from 99 postion - length 13

Things want to achieve -

1. Writing Unique ID and Sequence to exact same postion (Postion - 26 and 99 respectively)
2. Unique ID/Sequence No. can vary according to the Database value. Its total length is of fixed length (19 and 13 character). 
   If the value in Database is smaller than 19 or 13 , I need to prefix'0' before both numbers

Is there any way I can achieve this using shell script ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear! What is it that you actually want to do? Write a file? Modify a database? Can you give a sensible example of what you start with and what you end with?

Comment: Hi Mark,

I want to write below content to a file using shell scripting.
06                       0006488863669006814060110090302073350000000                      201705310000000002599. 


In this line two values namely Unique ID-0006488863669006111 and Sequence - 0000000002599 are the variable values which I will be getting from database and replacing it here.

Comment: Now I have two question - 1. how can I change that to other value and the exact position (say 26th and 99th position on line)? 2.How can I add '0' (zero) as a prefix to those two values to satisfy the length constraint using shell scripting?